# Refresh page selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, refresh

Heyy ^^ I'm coding a selenium program, but I'm stuck in one place. This program is made to buy 1 graphics card, on a French site, for my son's birthday. So there you have it, I coded everything but now my concern is that the web page of this graphics card is only available when it is in stock so the program cannot find the button by xpath "add to cart" . So I had the idea to make a loop so that as long as the "add to cart" button is not available, the program opens the page of the graphics card to infinity (like this when it is available, the button appears and the rest is done). However, I don't know how to achieve this condition, this loop, can you help me?
I am on selenium with webdriver

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Why the heading is refresh ?

Comment: i use python with jupyterlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addtocart = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('somexpath')
while (not addtocart):
    time.sleep(10)  # wait for 10 seconds
    driver.refresh()
    addtocart = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('somexpath')  # refind to avoid stale element exception
addtocart[0].click()
```

just use find elements and check for returned array length is zero or not

Comment: It writes this to me:
File "<ipython-input-226-37c13df2aeaf>", line 2
    while(not addtocart):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

it designates the "w" of while

Comment: see the updated answer beautified it , format it properly when you copy it to some editor if ti doesn't work

Comment: updated last line to use element from the array

Comment: you can accept only one answer , which ever is more suited for you

Comment: @PDHide : I appreciate the way you said _which ever is more suited for you_. Good work

Comment: Heyyyyy ^^ I would like to know what is the command to clear all cookies ^^
Thank you

Comment: delete_all_cookies()

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=refresh#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.delete_all_cookies

Comment: Thank you so much ^^ I would like to have the command to simulate the "enter" key on my keyboard. How can I do ? Please

Answer (score 0):

You can have a infinite loop like this :

**Explanation** :

while True is basically a infinite loop, in that we are trying to find

**Add to cart  xpath here** button with xpath and using `find_elements` so that if it is found then obviously size will be more than 0 then go ahead and click it but if not then go to else block and wait for 60 seconds (you can have any time here) and then refresh the page and do it all over again.

```
while True:
    try:
        if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "Add to cart  xpath here")) > 0:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "Add to cart  xpath here").click()
            break
        else:
            sleep(60)
            driver.refresh()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: it won't exit from the while loop ,

Comment: @PDHide - yeah break is required. Thnx I have fixed it

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you. Please accept it if it was helpfu, you will have to click on check mark which is under the votes button

Comment: Heyyyyy ^^ I would like to know what is the command to clear all cookies ^^ Thank you